# Faster way to push properties from descendant up in the xml-tree in XSLT 3.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Lets say I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <element>
    <someChildElement>
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="false"/>
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="true"/>
    </someChildElement>
    <someChildElement>
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="false"/>
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="false"/>
    </someChildElement>
    <someChildElement>
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="true"/>
    </someChildElement>
    <someChildElement>
      <someGrandchildElement/>
    </someChildElement>
  </element>
</root>
```

And I want this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root isImportant="true">
  <element isImportant="true">
    <someChildElement isImportant="true">
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="false"/>
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="true"/>
    </someChildElement>
    <someChildElement isImportant="false">
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="false"/>
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="false"/>
    </someChildElement>
    <someChildElement isImportant="true">
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="true"/>
    </someChildElement>
    <someChildElement isImportant="false">
      <someGrandchildElement isImportant="false"/>
    </someChildElement>
  </element>
</root>
```

Currently I'm using this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(@isImportant)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="isImportant" select="count(descendant::*[@isImportant='true']) gt 0"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And that gives me the correct result.
But with larger and deeper structures this is rather a slow and redundant approach.
Much better would be to start at the deepest element without the `@isImportant-attribute` and then go up the tree and reuse results of it descendants.

How can I do this in xslt?

Comment: Well, XSLT 3 has memo functions so you could consider writing one that returns and remembers the isImportant value of an element node but I don't know whether that is a good idea if your XML is that large that `descendant::*` is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a memo function would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:isImportant" as="xs:boolean" cache="yes" new-each-time="no">
    <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="if ($element/@isImportant)
              then $element/@isImportant = 'true'
              else if (not($element/*))
              then false()
              else some $child in $element/* satisfies mf:isImportant($child)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(@isImportant)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="isImportant" select="mf:isImportant(.)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whether that performs any better with some edition or version of an XSLT 3.0 processor I have not tested.

Comment: Interesting. And it gave me a 25% performance gain. Thank you.